# SQL Query to check rate limit

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I have a table of `messages` that users have sent, each with a timestamp.

I want to make a query that will tell me (historically) the most number of messages a user ever sent in an hour.

So in other words, in any given 1 hour period, what was the most number of messages sent.

Any ideas?

Comment: The solutions are coming as "sent in an hour from :00 to :59", but if you mean in any given 60 minute period, then it's more complicated and you should specify that.

Comment: do you want only the one person with the highest number of messages, or the highest number of messages PER PERSON...

Comment: @dkamins - yes any 60 minute period, thanks!  @DRapp - highest number for each user, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `timestamp` to be a DATETIME - otherwise, use [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) to convert to a DATETIME...

For a [rolling] count within the last hour:

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM MESSAGES m
   WHERE m.timestamp BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) 
                         AND NOW()
GROUP BY m.user
ORDER BY cnt DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

If you want a specific hour, specify the hour:

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM MESSAGES m
   WHERE m.timestamp BETWEEN '2011-06-06 14:00:00'
                         AND '2011-06-06 15:00:00'
GROUP BY m.user
ORDER BY cnt DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Awesome - the "rolling count" is what I had in mind.  This is the first solution I've seen that does that.  OMG Ponies, you are my hero.

Answer (score 2):

Need more details on table structure etc. but something like:

```
  select date(timestmp), hour(timestmp) , count(*) 
    from yourtable group by date(timestmp) , hour(timestmp)
    order by count(*) DESC
    limit 100;
```

would give you hte desired result.

Comment: Nice!  As someone pointed out above, would this only work for ":00 to :59" type hours?  Was hoping there was a way to do any 60 minute period regardless of when it start/stopped.  Not sure if this is feasible in any reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT MAX(PerHr) FROM 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS PerHr FROM messages WHERE msg_uid=? 
   GROUP BY msg_time/3600) t
```

Comment: (Here I was treating msg_time as storing time_t seconds, but if you are storing actual SQL TIME, then you can use SQL functions such as @James showed)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this would be horribly slow, but for an arbitrary historical max hour, something like this might work (downvote me if I'm way off, I'm not a MySQL person):

```
SELECT base.user, base.time, COUNT(later.time)
FROM messages base
INNER JOIN messages later ON later.time BETWEEN base.time AND DATE_ADD(base.time, INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND base.user = later.user
WHERE base.user = --{This query will only work for one user}
GROUP BY base.user, base.time
ORDER BY COUNT(later.time) DESC
LIMIT 1
```